# doctrine2 Jointable Annotation

Tags: doctrine-orm

I bet there is a really easy solution to this, but I just can't figure it out. If you need any extra info, please point it out.

I have 3 tables:

```
User
Job - ManyToMany User
JobReport - ManyToMany Job , ManyToMany User
```

Both user and job exists in db. So the php calls are:

```
$report = new JobReportEntity();

//get user
$userWhoReports = $this->getEntityManager()->getRepository("Entity\User")->find(1);

//get job
$queryBuilder = $this->em->createQueryBuilder()
    ->select(array('p', 'u'))
    ->from('Entity\Job', 'p')
    ->leftJoin('p.user', 'u')
    ->where('p.id = :id')
    ->setParameter('id', 1);

    $job = $queryBuilder->getQuery()->getResult();
    $job = $job[0];

$report->setUser($userWhoReports);
$report->setJob($job);
$report->setReportDate(new \Datetime('now'));
$report->setReason("reason");
$this->getEntityManager()->persist($report);
$this->getEntityManager()->flush();
```

Everything seems to work. Here are the entities:

UserEntity:

```
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * User
 *
 * @Entity
 * @Table(name="user", uniqueConstraints={
 *   @UniqueConstraint(name="unique_name",columns={"username"}),
 * })
 */
class User
{
    /**
     * @Id
     * @Column(type="integer");
     * @GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    protected $id;

    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    public function setId($id)
    {
        $this->id = (int) $id;
    }

    public function getUsername()
    {
        return $this->username;
    }

    public function setUsername($username)
    {
        $this->username = $username;
    }
}
```

JobEntity:

```
<?php
namespace Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * Job
 *
 * @Entity
 * @Table(name="job")
 */
class Job
{
    /**
     * @Id
     * @Column(type="integer");
     * @GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    protected $id;

    //..
    /**
     * @Column(type="integer")
     */
    protected $user_id;

    /**
     * @ManyToOne(targetEntity="User")
     * @JoinColumn(name="user_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     */
    protected $user;

    /**
     * @ManyToMany(targetEntity="JobTag")
     * @JoinTable(name="job_tags",
     *      joinColumns={@JoinColumn(name="job_id", referencedColumnName="id")},
     *      inverseJoinColumns={@JoinColumn(name="job_tag_id", referencedColumnName="id")}
     * )
     */
    protected $tags;

    public function __construct() {
        $this->tags = new \Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection();
    }

    public function getTags()
    {
        return $this->tags;
    }

    public function addTag(JobTag $tag)
    {
        //$tag->addJob($this);
        $this->tags[] = $tag;
    }

    public function removeTag(JobTag $tag)
    {
        foreach($this->tags as $k => $t)
        {
            if ($t->getId() == $tag->getId())
            {
                //$t->removeJob($this);
                unset($this->tags[$k]);
                return;
            }
        }
    }

    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    public function setId($id)
    {
        $this->id = (int) $id;
    }

    public function getUser()
    {
        return $this->user;
    }

    public function setUser($user)
    {
        $this->user = $user;
    }

}
```

JobReportEntity:

```
<?php
namespace Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
/**
 * Job
 *
 * @Entity
 * @Table(name="job_report", uniqueConstraints={
 *   @UniqueConstraint(name="multiple_reports_from_the_same_user",columns={"job_id", "user_id"}),
 * })
 */
class JobReport
{
    /**
     * @Id
     * @Column(type="integer");
     * @GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    protected $id;

    /**
     * @Column(type="integer")
     */
    protected $user_id;

    /**
     * @ManyToMany(targetEntity="User")
     * @JoinColumn(name="user_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     */
    protected $user;

    /**
     * @Column(type="integer")
     */
    protected $job_id;

    /**
     * @ManyToMany(targetEntity="Job")
     * @JoinColumn(name="job_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     */
    protected $job;

    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    public function setId($id)
    {
        $this->id = (int) $id;
    }

    public function getUser()
    {
        return $this->user;
    }

    public function setUser($user)
    {
        $this->user = $user;
    }

    public function getJob()
    {
        return $this->job;
    }

    public function setJob($job)
    {
        $this->job = $job;
    }
}
```

Everything seems normal? The only thing I am not sure it works is jobtags. There is a join table for job and job tags. ManyToMany made with @joinTable.

Here it is:

```
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * Job
 *
 * @Entity
 * @Table(name="job_tag", uniqueConstraints={
 *   @UniqueConstraint(name="name",columns={"name"}),
 * })
 */
class JobTag
{
    /**
     * @Id
     * @Column(type="integer");
     * @GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    protected $id;
    //..

    /**
     * @Column(type="integer")
     */
    protected $user_id;

    /**
     * @ManyToOne(targetEntity="User")
     * @JoinColumn(name="user_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     */
    protected $user;

    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    public function setId($id)
    {
        $this->id = (int) $id;
    }

    public function getUser()
    {
        return $this->user;
    }

    public function setUser($user)
    {
        $this->user = $user;
    }
}
```

Here is the problem:

Catchable fatal error: Argument 1 passed to Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection::__construct() must be of the type array, object given, called in /vendor/doctrine/orm/lib/Doctrine/ORM/UnitOfWork.php on line 547 and defined in /vendor/doctrine/collections/lib/Doctrine/Common/Collections/ArrayCollection.php on line 47

How would I debug this?

And kind of help will be very much appricated :)

Many thanks,

Ioan-Catalin B.

Answer (score 0):

If i am not mistaken, @ManyToMany annotation could be used only with @JoinTable.

```
/**
 * Territory
 *
 * @ORM\Table()
 */
class Territory
{
/**
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="House", inversedBy="territories")
     * @ORM\JoinTable(name="territory_house",
     *      joinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="territory_id", referencedColumnName="id")},
     *      inverseJoinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="house_id", referencedColumnName="id")}
     * )
     */
    private $houses;
}

/**
 * House
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="house")
 */
class House
{
/**
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Territory", mappedBy="houses")
     */
    private $territories;
}
```